# Running a procedure no matter what text box is double clicked on an Access 2010 form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with over 500 text boxes on it.
When I double click one of them I have a procedure tied to the On Dbl Click event.

What I want to happen is to have that same code (albiet with different variables passed) run no matter which of the 500 text boxes I double click.
The only way I know how would be to write 500 `Private Sub DblClick(Cancel as integer)` procedures.
That would work but there must be another way surely.
I don't like the idea of having basically the same code copied 500 times just so one instance is pointing to one of the 500 text boxes.

Comment: Nope, it worked. I just change the "=doubleClick()" to be "=doubleclick('" & variable & "')". My doubleclick function was declared as Function doubleClick(var as string) as string. Works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the below code to ms-access form. If any of the textbox is double clicked it will call the `doubleClick` function.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim ctl As Control

    For Each ctl In Me
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            ctl.OnDblClick = "=doubleClick()"
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub


Function doubleClick() As String
    MsgBox "function called"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Would never have thought of doing it like that.